# Comparing 2 MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database that I need to check to see if the person is not in one of them. I have one table that stores firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zip for samples. Then there is a customers table that also has this information. What I need to do is figure out what people from the samples have not become customers. I have not the first clue on how to run a query for this as i have tried multiple joins and what not to no avail. Any help in figuring out how to find out what sample people have not become customers would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: and... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA` LEFT JOIN `customers` ON `tableA`.`id`=`customers`.`id` WHERE `customers`.`id` IS NULL
```

It should work because when you left join it takes all records from both tables and connects them.  If there isn't a record for the second table, it replaces the columns with null; therefore if they are not a customer the columns are null.

Comment: Why escape all the table/fieldnames? None are reserved words. Please don't be a Microsoft Access cargo cultee.

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't. query readability comes from proper indentation and appropriate line breaks at critical points.

Comment: I can't talk about the escaping as I am not a database person, but this query worked for what I was working for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This attempts to match the person to customer based on first and last name (address is commented out, or add city, zip, state as required).
Where the join is not successful, it means the person never became a customer (not by the same first/last name at least) - this is  tested using the `c.firstname IS NULL` condition

```
select p.*
from person p
left join customer c on
   on p.firstname = c.firstname
  and p.lastname  = c.lastname
 #and p.address   = c.address
where c.firstname is null
```

Comment: This one brought back all my records from the free sample table. Thank you for your help on the little information I gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*
    FROM samples s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                         FROM customers c
                         WHERE s.firstName = c.firstName
                           AND s.lastName = c.lastName
                           AND s.address = c.address                                 
                           AND s.city = c.city                                 
                           AND s.state = c.state                                 
                           AND s.zip = c.zip)
```